# How to load attribute directive dynamically in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dynamic-loading

I am trying to load directive dynamically using values in an object. To do that I have tried following :

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div {{testDirectiveJson.first}}-directive></div>
    <div {{testDirectiveJson.sec}}-directive></div>
    <div {{testDirectiveJson.third}}-directive></div>
    <script src="./test.directive.js"></script>
</body>
```

here is my js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.testDirectiveJson = {
         first: '1',
         sec: '2',
         third: '3',
     }
     $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 }).directive("1Directive", function() {

     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive A!</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("2Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! B</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("3Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! C</h1>"
     };
 });
```

but its not working as expected. I have lots of condition on which i have to change my view dynamically so I need some way in which i just change in my object and view will react to it.

please help to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by creating another directive and dynamically adding the attribute to the elements you need.
[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/dhanrajv/Lvc0u55v/13070/)